# Accessing object in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

i have the following nested form :

```
<%= form_for @contrat,:url => backend_orders_update_report_url(@contrat) do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :contrat_lines do |fcl| %>
    <%=  fcl.object.inspect  %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

the output is the following :

```
nil
```

In the nested forms i want to display a few elements not as form but as raw text and a few ones as form field. Usually in a form by doing f.object.name, i would access the name and be able to display it as I want. However, here if i do fcl.object, there is only nil. It should display the inspection of a contrat_line object.

Is it possible to access the data in a nested form?

EDIT :

the controller action :

```
def show_report
  @contrat = Contrat.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here is what models look like with the relation at the beggining :

ContratLine :

```
class ContratLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Priceable

  belongs_to :contrat
  belongs_to :good
  #a enlever ici et dans la base
  attr_accessible :active_start,:active,:good_id,:pricing,:contrat
  validates :active_start, :presence=> true,:if => "active"
  validate :active_start_smaller_than_active_stop
  validate :active_start_day_cannot_be_greater_than_28
  has_one :pricing, :as => :priceable, :dependent => :delete
  before_validation :convert_month_year_to_date
  after_save :set_user_subscription_date
```

Contrat :

```
class Contrat < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :contrat_lines, :dependent => :delete_all

  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :user_id,:pricing_id,:state,:adresse_id,:adresse,:payment,:adresse_attributes,:automatic,:start_date,:end_date
  enum_attr :state, %w(basket waiting_data to_confirm paid) do
    labels :basket=>'Panier',  :to_confirm=>'Non payé',:paid=>'Payé'
  end
  enum_attr :payment, %w(debit_card wire_transfer cheque direct_debit)
  belongs_to :adresse
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :adresse, :allow_destroy => true
  scope :by_state,  lambda { |state| where("state = ?",state) }
  scope :last_automatic, where("automatic = true").order("invoice_date DESC")
  scope :last_with_adresse, where("state != 'basket'").order("invoice_date DESC")

  before_validation :set_numbers
```

Comment: How your models look like? Could you post some model code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an accepts_nested_attributes_for :contrat_lines as well as :contrat_lines_attributes in attr_accessible